# Lists next to floated elements: How to get list items in the right place?

Tags: css, list, html-lists

This fiddle shows the basic problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/boldewyn/Qvfgv/

There is a floated element and next to it a list in the main flow. The list items extend into the space of the floated element.

A workaround is to use `overflow: hidden` on the `<ul>`. But then the list doesn't 'flow' around the div anymore but stays at the right all the time, which is undesired for all the white space below the floated element.

#### What I'm looking for:

- The list should float around the floated block, and the list items should stay out of the floated block's area. Altrnatively it's ok for single `<li>` elements to be pushed right (e.g., via `overflow: hidden`).
- A pure CSS solution without background images or JavaScript. This is for a print preview page, which must additionally be tailored for people w/o JavaScript and down to IE7.
- The list bullets should be exdented on the left, just like the browser's default. That means, list items next to the floated element should gain an extra space to it to place the bullet in it.

#### What doesn't work:

- using background images I could give the individual list items padding and would be set. But this is not reliable enough, because the page's intent is to be printed.
- I don't know the exact width or height of the floated element. If I did, I could fix the problem with `li { margin-left: "floated-element's width" + 20px; }`.
- I experimented a bit with combos of `text-indent`, `list-style-position` and such, but haven't been able to come up with a useful solution.

It may well be, that there is no CSS-only solution for this. This question is literally my last resort before telling the customer that it's not possible.

Comment: what exactly you need? where is the right palace of list item? I am bit confused here :(

Comment: It doesn't seem possible with your constraints. This is the closest I could get: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Qvfgv/6/. I don't think it's good enough. It's bad in IE9, so you'd have to set different numbers in that browser.

Answer (score 2):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qvfgv/4/) what you're after?

I've just increased the `margin-right` of the block from `10px` to `30px`.

**Edit**

I think I've got the effect you want, but it may be a bit too hacky for your needs - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qvfgv/7/)

Comment: In principle yes, but then all the other elements, like `<p>` and `<h1>` are wrongly positioned when next to the floated element. +1 because it looks like what I want, but I cannot accept the answer, sorry.

Comment: @Boldewyn Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: @Boldewyn I've got another solution that involves `overflow:hidden` on the `li`s and `padding`, negative `text-indent` and `list-style:inside`, see my edit.

Comment: I have given you +1 coz it seems you are getting closer to the solutions...:D

Comment: Yes, that would cut it, but it is a bit too fragile. On my machine an 1/8th of the bullet point is cut off. Apart from that if Pankaj hadn't the idea with `position:relative`, I had accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `position: relative;` is the best solution I've found, just be sure to add padding or a margin to the right to compensate for the offset. This works with `list-style-position` set to `inside` or `outside`. You just need to adjust the offset accordingly.

```
ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 3em;
  margin-right: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

list item bullets often seem to sit further left than they should. The answer is simple: add some left margin to your `<li>`'s or left padding to your `<ul>`. That will shift everything to the right.

I typically see this behaviour in sites that use CSS resets because `ul,li {margin:0;padding:0}` will give the behaviour you're seeing. In fact your fiddle does this:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

So yeah, you're actually aligning the text with the left edge but not the bullet which goes past the edge (that's some kind of CSS quirk I guess). In your case you have a 20px left padding on ul but that doesn't seem to be enough, try putting it on the li or using margins.

Comment: Nope. You wouldn't think I haven't tried that. If you give the list item left margin, it is consumed by the area above the floated element. After the margin the list bullet comes, then, coinciding with the floated element's border the list element starts. However, I invite you to prove me wrong in a JSFiddle. That would be great.

Comment: With "above" I mean something like the z-axis. Margin starts to kick in as soon as it exceeds the width of the floated element. If you remove all the "reset" stuff from the fiddle, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with TomWardrop in that the best solution i have found to ensure that nested list indents are consistent when next to a floated element or not is to reset the padding and using relative positioning with a left setting.

```
ul {
  position: relative;
  padding-left:0;
  margin-left:0;
  left: 1em;
}
```

[See fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/9neryfnp/2/)

Update.

If you want the inset only on nested lists and to keep the first level inline with paragraph. Set left to 0 for ul css declaration and then:

```
ul ul {
  left:1em;
}
```

[see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9neryfnp/3/)